# Collection sorting encounter error . java

Tags: java

The code i did do not work for collection. is there other way to sort an object arraylist? or how to sort it using collection.sort?

```
                Object [] objects = BookAnalyser.array.toArray();
        ArrayList<Object> uniqueword = new ArrayList<Object>();
        
        for (Object h:  BookAnalyser.WordList.findUnique(objects, objects)){
            if(h != null ) {
                uniqueword.add(h);
            }
        }
        Collections.sort((uniqueword)); //Error: The method sort(List<T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Object>) 


        for(Object j : uniqueword) {
            System.out.print(j+ " ");
        }
```

It shows The method sort(List) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList). Normally it would work just fine.

Comment: You can use `Arrays.sort()`, but you'll need a Comparable type (like `String[]`) or a custom Comparator.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to sort a `List<T>` where `T` is `Object`.

The definition of `Collections.sort` is

> ```
> static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort​(List<T> list)
> ```

which means the type parameter must implement `Comparable<? super T>`, which `Object` does not.

Two solutions:

1. Make `uniqueword` a list of some type implementing `Comparable`, such as `String`
2. Provide your own custom `Comparator<Object>`, but you'll have to downcast to something that can be compared, so the first option (`List<String>` for example) is much preferred.

Comment: In the second option you need to specify the comparator object as the second argument of `sort()`.